# Error: Mailaddress already exists in Organisation

Tags: email, exchange-2003, email-server, domain-controller

I have two Domain Controllers for one domain and need to transfer an smtp-address from one user to another. I deleted the mailaddress from the first and when trying to add it to the second user, I get the error Id c103412e7, "this Mailaddress already exists in your organisation". However, when searching for the mailaddress via the Advanced Search via LDAP-String "proxyAddresses=smtp:xxx@example.com", It doesn't show the address anymore. I tried manually synchronizing both domain controllers with each other, but did not have any luck.

Any ideas on why the mailaddress still seems to exist somewhere?

Comment: Two hours later, I was able to add the address. However, I will have this problem more than once in the future - any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Exchange takes time to process scheduled tasks. When you removed the email address for one user it doesn't occur straight away. Exchange puts it in a queue and processes it later one. This is the case for a lot of what Exchange does.

You just need to be patient and wait for the change to occur. Whenever I remove something I generally wait 15 minutes to allow time for the server to process the request and continue on with the job after that. I am not sure if Exchange has a set time for this or not, haven't had any luck finding a definitive answer, just that it takes time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - any hints on where I can enforce a synchronization or immediate running of the task?